# How to change focus in in Xamarin.Forms after a scanner was triggered?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app for a warehouse, we use the [Zebra TC25](https://www.zebra.com/de/de/products/mobile-computers/handheld/tc25.html), which has a build in barcode scanner. The scanner works fine and delivers codes.

I have a grid, as shown below, and I want to move the focus to the next text-field (Entry) after a scan has occured. Now I have a callback method which gets triggered after a scan has happened.

**My question:** How can I have an elegant way of knowing which element has focus and which should be the next?

I have tried using `TabIndex` - it was ignored.
I have tried giving them names just like below, and then use a dictionary, which maps each Entry-element to the next one to be focused. There I had to iterate over the Keys, and then call something like `_focusOrder[entry].Focus();`, which is also not the most pretty solution. Specially considering that there are going to be a few forms with more that just 3 codes to be scanned.

**Note**: The scanner is implemented as a keyboard, and I don't have to set the value from the scanner in my callback - it just works out-of-the-box. Therefore I don't keep track on the focused item, as it is not necessary (for the input).

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Von" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=VonLagerplatz}" x:Name="_vonEntry"   />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Nach" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=NachLagerplatz}" x:Name="_nachEntry" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Artikel" />
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Artikel}" x:Name="_artikelEntry" />
    </Grid>
```

**Optimal solutions:** (which I could not make work, cause it is my first Xamarin app)

Make the `TabIndex`-property work.
Use an attached property, where I can reference the next element in XAML. So have something like `<Entry .... x:Name="_vonEntry" NextElement="{Reference _nachEntry}" />`

Comment: So basically you want to iterate through all the entry controls in your page and change focus one after the other?

Comment: When you tried the TabIndex: Did you actually send a tab at the end of a scan or an enter key? As far as I know the default value for zebra scanners is enter but it can be reconfigured https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/evm/add-a-tab-key-after-scanning-a-bar-code.html

Comment: @G.hakim yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: @AndreKraemer I don't have control over the barcodes. We scan everyday products like beer bottels or a bag of chips. Do I get more info if I log in? Cause I see only some barcodes for now.

Comment: As far as I know, you can configure the whole device to always send a specific key at the end of a scan. I believe that we did that using the EMDK Manager

Comment: If it's a zebra scanner, i think you just scan a barcode to set it to add a tab at the end of each input. https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/evm/add-a-tab-key-after-scanning-a-bar-code.html

Comment: @RamziKhahil Does this be helpful ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949977/set-focus-to-next-entry-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to write a custom behaviour that you attach to your entries. Something like this:

```
<Entry x:Name="VonEntry" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <custom:NextElementOnReturn Element="{x:Reference NachEntry}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>

<Entry x:Name="NachEntry" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

You would have to implement the behaviour `NextElementOnReturn` by yourself. As far as I know there's nothing builtin.

There's a nice tutorial about behaviours here to get you startet https://blog.xamarin.com/extend-xamarin-forms-controls-functionality-with-behaviors/